# SharePoint List calculation using current date

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, error, calculated-column-formula

I am relatively new to SharePoint lists and trying to use  calculation to determine an action status as either Open, Closed or Overdue. I have tried the formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date Closed]),"",(IF([Date Closed]<>"","Closed",(IF(]Due Date]<Today(),"Overdue","Open")))))
```

When I use this I am getting a syntax error, from what I have managed to gather is that the Today() function is not recognized in SharePoint.

Can anyone please advise a solution for this.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use calculated column formula like this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date Closed]),IF([Due Date]<Today(),"Overdue","Open"),"Closed")
```

**Notes**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.